# in Java, how do I define different methods for an interface array? Using hash tables without java library

Tags: java

I have a programming problem in Java:

Can I define a different method for any different interface array element?

```
myInterface[] op = new myInterface[4];
```

Now "myInterface" only has 1 method: `public static int doSomething(int a, int b);`.

I need to define that method to do different things with the numbers based on the element id (0-3).

Restrictions:

1. must use hash tables.
2. no switch-case or if statements (because of hash tables)
3. cannot under any circumstance use the Java defined hash tables

i.e. if I call `op[0].doSomething(2,3)` it'll output `12` (2^2 * 3)
and if I call `op[1].doSomething(2,3)` it'll output `5` (2+3).

EDIT: I'd like to know if its possible or am I chasing my tail?
if it is could someone suggest a way for it to be done, I don't need the entire answer just suggestions, please.

P.S. Also I looked at all the pages on interfaces in Java, haven't found anything helpful.

Comment: googling keeps getting me java hash tables library results...

Comment: -1: Sorry, wrong place for this post.  Read the FAQ.  Then either write some code, and post your code on stackoverflow, or get help from your instructor or classmates.  Don't just assign *your* homework to us.

Comment: @kevin-cline i dont know if its possible so i have no code that could do anything, al i have is an interface, which i wrote out (3 lines total in file) and another class that has that array that i wrote in main. Should i write that out? I that what you mean?

Comment: The term you should probably google is "polymorphism".

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by hashtable usage, but `<interface>[]` is actually `<any_class_that_implements_interface>[]`. Create classes that implements the given interface with different implementation for the required method and put the objects of each into the array, then when you call the method, each object will behave as you require

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

```
class interface operations { public int doSomething(int a, int b) {} }

public class test {
    public static void main(...) {
    operations[] ops = new operations[4];
    ops[0] = new operations() {public int doSomething(int a, int b) {return a-b*a;}};
...etc.
}
```

Answer: use anonymous classes.

Comment: the hash tables bit is the array whos id goes to different definitions of the function.

Comment: Class and interface names should be spelled with capital letters, and you're using interface definitions wrong (don't use static).

Comment: Linking to documentation on how anonymous classes work would be useful to the asker. Also, this answer does not use hash tables, which the requester stipulated.

Comment: @ftr yea, my bad, I actually didnt write 'static' in my code, but here i did, i'll edit it out, thanks.

Comment: @sgmorrison yea i didnt write it out but i used chars and converted to ints `asciiCode = (int)someChar;`   The chars are then used as ID's to different anonymous classes' functions.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this approach

```
public class MyInterface{
  private int numberInStack;

public MyInterface(int num){
  this.numberInStack = num;
}

public static int doSomething(int a, int b){
  switch (numberInStack):
  case 0: {
    return  a-b*a;    
  }
  //... all other cases

}
```

And then later on in the code

```
 MyInterface[] op = new MyInterface[4];
 op[0] = new MyInterface(0);
```

But this suggest that there is countable and reasonable number of things what `doSomething` can actually do and that it will actually always return `int`. In other ways I would use the approach in first answer

Comment: looks cool, but not what i needed. The point of this was to use hash tables instead of switch-cases and if-elses. It was a simplified point to demonstrate that on a large scale server, it would cost less precious CPU cycles by skipping comparing a long list of conditions. Simply because, what if you had 1000 different operations you had to do. But thanks, i didnt know the stack could be made useful in that way.

Comment: As I said in the answer - my assumption here was that there will be, say, maximum 10 items in the stack. In small numbers that approach is understandable. But if you tend to have 1000 items in stack, then my aproach is no no

Comment: i probably should have mentioned this fact in the question...i just used '4' for simplicity's sake.

Answer (score 0):

### Is static usage a bad idea for you?

I think at chapter 2 of [Effective Java](http://cyclo.ps/books/Prentice.Hall.Effective.Java.2nd.Edition.May.2008.pdf), and above all, at **chapter 33 (EnumMap)**